# TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, typeerror

I have done the search and the existing comments on same error was not helpful

The line:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user = 'root', passwd = '', db='vendors', port='3306')
```

throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqlpython.py", line 12, in <module>
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1', user = 'root', passwd = '', db='vendors', port='3306')
  File "/apollo/env/AWSSDKMetrics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/apollo/env/AWSSDKMetrics/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 188, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What is the reference to the integer? Which field is it referring to? Keep in mind that I am not a python programmer or developer.

Comment: Looks like `port='3306' should be port=3306`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the port as a number, not a string:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='127.0.0.1',
    user='root', passwd='',
    db='vendors', 
    port=3306)
```

I used multiple lines to make the above example more readable; the error points out that the value for `port` must be an integer.

Comment: eww! That was so silly. I was thinking of the IP address as anumber as well and hence making the same quotes around the port. I have different errors now. I will search through and come back if I need more help